# Gitlab: Passing artefacts through jobs and stages

Tags: node.js, gitlab, mocha.js, gitlab-ci

I use node.js mocha and selenium-webdriver for e2e testing.
I have different stages, like install, test button 1, test button 2.
Each stage (except install) have 2 jobs (for chrome and for safari).
My goal, in the end, get 1 txt file with tests results from all jobs of all stages.

I tried many different configurations:

1. always pass artifact report.txt and run ./mocha >> report.txt in each job.

   - result in inconsistent data in the file (not all jobs write in, partially wroten etc.)
2. always pass 2 artifacts report1.txt, report2.txt, so the job for chrome write only in #1, the job for the safari in #2

   - doesn't work at all, god knows why
3. dependencies with 2 artifacts report1.txt, report2.txt

   - for some reason artifact node_modules which generates in install stage not passing to next stages.

I don't have examples anymore for this setups, they are messy, but I give you an example of my .gitlab-ci.yml maybe you can help me with it.

```
stages:
  - install
  - startup
  - quality
  - language
  - report

.chrome_template: &chrome_template
  environment:
    name: chrome
  variables: &chrome_template_var
    SELENIUM_BROWSER: chrome
  tags:
    - "macbook"

.safari_template: &safari_template
  environment:
    name: safari
  variables: &safari_template_var
    SELENIUM_BROWSER: safari
  tags:
    - "macbook"

# install job

install:
  stage: install
  tags:
    - "macbook"
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  except:
    - tags

# testing jobs

.startup: &startup
  stage: startup
  variables: &startup-var
    SPEC: startup
  script:
    - npm run test
  retry: 1
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - screenshot

.quality: &quality
  stage: quality
  variables: &quality-var
    SPEC: quality
  script:
    - npm run test
  retry: 1
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - screenshot/

.language: &language
  stage: language
  variables: &language-var
    SPEC: language
  script:
    - npm run test
  retry: 1
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - screenshot/

startup:chrome:
  <<: *startup
  <<: *chrome_template
  variables:
    <<: *startup-var
    <<: *chrome_template_var

language:chrome:
  <<: *language
  <<: *chrome_template
  variables:
    <<: *language-var
    <<: *chrome_template_var

quality:chrome:
  <<: *quality
  <<: *chrome_template
  variables:
    <<: *quality-var
    <<: *chrome_template_var

startup:safari:
  <<: *startup
  <<: *safari_template
  variables:
    <<: *startup-var
    <<: *safari_template_var

language:safari:
  <<: *language
  <<: *safari_template
  variables:
    <<: *language-var
    <<: *safari_template_var

quality:safari:
  <<: *quality
  <<: *safari_template
  variables:
    <<: *quality-var
    <<: *safari_template_var

report:
  stage: report
  tags:
    - "macbook"
  script:
    - cat *.txt > report.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - report.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least couple of possible problems in the file you posted:

1. `artifacts.name` is not defined so the default "artifacts" string would be used. This poses a risk of overwriting one artifact file with another when multiple jobs runs in parallel on the same host.
   Define the custom [artifacts:name](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsname) to fix overwrites.
2. If you store `report.txt` at the same folder, then please rename it before finishing the job, so report file will not be overwritten on your `report` stage job, where all requested artifact archives would be unpacked to the same location.
3. Seems like none of the jobs *(startup, quality, language)* exports `report.txt` file. Add `report.txt` along with `screenshots` folder to export it.
4. Screenshots *(and reports)* would be exported only when job fails. If it's not the wanted behavior, change [artifacts:when](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactswhen) to `on_success` or `always`
5. The whole pipeline fails if one of the test jobs will fail. If this pipeline is only about testing & exporting results, you should allow test jobs to fail without failing the whole pipeline with [allow_failure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure)

Summarizing everything written above, here's the proposed changed yml file:

```
stages:
  - install
  - test
  - report

#
# Templates
#

# Tags can't be defined on a global scope for now
# Ref: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23434
.default: &default
  tags: ['macbook']

.node_modules:
  artifacts: &node_modules
    paths: ['node_modules']
    when: always

.test_reports:
  artifacts: &test_reports
    paths:
      - screenshot
      - reports
    when: always

.chrome_template: &chrome_template
  environment:
    name: chrome
  variables: &chrome_template_var
    SELENIUM_BROWSER: chrome

.safari_template: &safari_template
  environment:
    name: safari
  variables: &safari_template_var
    SELENIUM_BROWSER: safari

#
# Jobs
#

# Install

install:
  <<: *default
  stage: install
  except: ['tags']
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts: *node_modules

# Test

.test: &test
  <<: *default
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run test
    # Move report to individual file to fix overwriting it by other artifacts
    - mkdir -p reports
    - mv report.txt reports/report_${CI_JOB_NAME}.txt
  retry: 1
  artifacts: *test_reports
  # Allow tests to fail, exporting artifacts to the final stage
  allow_failure: true

.test_startup: &test_startup
  <<: *test
  variables: &startup_var
    SPEC: startup

.test_quality: &test_quality
  <<: *test
  variables: &quality_var
    SPEC: quality

.test_language: &test_language
  <<: *test
  variables: &language_var
    SPEC: language


test:startup:chrome:
  <<: *test_startup
  <<: *chrome_template
  variables:
    <<: *startup_var
    <<: *chrome_template_var

test:language:chrome:
  <<: *test_language
  <<: *chrome_template
  variables:
    <<: *language_var
    <<: *chrome_template_var

test:quality:chrome:
  <<: *test_quality
  <<: *chrome_template
  variables:
    <<: *quality_var
    <<: *chrome_template_var

test:startup:safari:
  <<: *test_startup
  <<: *safari_template
  variables:
    <<: *startup_var
    <<: *safari_template_var

test:language:safari:
  <<: *test_language
  <<: *safari_template
  variables:
    <<: *language_var
    <<: *safari_template_var

test:quality:safari:
  <<: *test_quality
  <<: *safari_template
  variables:
    <<: *quality_var
    <<: *safari_template_var

# Report

report:
  <<: *default
  stage: report
  script:
    # Summarize reports before exporting
    # Ignore errors when there are no reports to export
    - cat reports/*.txt > report.txt | true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - screenshot
      - report.txt
```

Please check if multiple failed test jobs don't overwrite the content of "screenshot" folder. Otherwise you'd need to move screenshots in the same manner as it's done with "report.txt" file.